# Sql server fast growing table approach

Tags: sql-server

The challenge is that I'll have to have a table which encounters a lot of traffic. According to my calculations an insert of 1 row will happen every 200-400ms, and there also will be many selects. As you can imagine this table will grow pretty fast.

I figured I could go with read uncommitted isolation level to improve performance (?).

How about inserts? Will it much of a burden to the server?

Should I even use indexes if table is getting so many inserts?

I was thinking, to hold this data in memory and update database periodically, but then we risk losing data if anything crashes.

Second thought is to build archive table, and move data from main table to archive table periodically.

Any other ideas how I should approach this?

Answer (score 0):

So a few thoughts...

First is of the Other thoughts variety... Create a table space for the table and make sure it's on a super fast drive :)

There is an overhead with creating or updating an index so you'll have to experiment with an approach.

If the data is critical then I wouldn't hold it in memory before saving it, if you can live with some loses then hold in memory and saving periodically might work but experimenting and figuring out what the sweet spot is will be a good idea.

I'm guessing you'll definitely need to archive the data as you're talking about 7.2 million records a month, of course depends on how wide your table is?

Everything you do with your database is a burden on the server, your question is how much you do and can a specific server cope. I'm guessing people would need more info to advise. Is it just this table on the server? Is it part of a larger database?

I would say that research and experiment is the way to go with this one before diving into building anything for production.

Answer (score 0):

> Any other ideas how I should approach this?

Test. Test. Test.

Don't use "read uncommitted".  Use READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT or SNAPSHOT isolation to ensure that reads and writes don't conflict.  These use [Row Versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-ver15) instead of locking to provide a readers with a consistent view of the database.

But this sounds like a good scenario for a [clustered columnstore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver15).  Rows are initially loaded into a "Delta Store", then every 1 million rows, the Delta Store is transformed into a set of highly-compressed column segments.  It provides the highest compression and fastest scanning of any table type.

You might further consider [partitioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15) the table by, say, year, to facilitate a rolling window of data retention.

If you decide that you can't afford to wait for each row to be hardened to the log, and you are willing to accept some data loss in case of a failure, you can turn on [Delayed Durability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/control-transaction-durability?view=sql-server-ver15), and SQL Server will not make you wait for a Log flush for every transaction. Although at merely 10s of inserts per second, I don't imagine that will be an issue.  A single-threaded client doing single-row-per-transaction inserts should have no trouble scaling to several hundred rows per second.  If the client batches rows into transactions, or there are multiple concurrent clients loading then 10x that.